# PHP variable in callback function

Tags: php, callback

I've a question. In array_filter:

```
$min = 4;
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$arr = array_filter($arr,function($e) {
    return $e <= 4;
});
var_dump($arr);
```

It works.

If i use a

```
$min = 4;
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$arr = array_filter($arr,function($e) {
    return $e <= $min;//$min variable gives error
});
var_dump($arr);
```

How to put correctly, that it see can the $min variable in callback?

Thank you for hints

Answer (score 7):

```
$min = 4;
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$arr = array_filter($arr,function($e) use($min) {
    return $e <= $min;
});
var_dump($arr);
```

note: int PHP 5.4 you can use $this in closures

Answer (score 0):

> $min = 4;
>
> $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
>
> $arr = array_filter($arr,function($e)
>
> {
>
> global $min;
>
> ```
> return $e <= $min;//$min variable gives error
> ```
>
> });